# Flutter for web routing with multiple material apps

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have an issue regarding the routing of the flutter for the web. For specific reasons in my project, I have multiple material apps. So the platform that I'm building is a material app, let's name it 'Parent'. In this material app at some point lower in the widget tree I have a child that is also a material app let's name it 'Child'. When the user arrives at the point in the Parent tree where Child is rendered, it looks like the routing of Parent is replaced with the actual routing of Child. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Since I can't share the actual code I've recreated a minimal example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ParentApp());
}

class ParentApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentAppState createState() => _ParentAppState();
}

class _ParentAppState extends State<ParentApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Parent',
      initialRoute: '/parent-home',
      routes: {
        '/parent-home': (context) => ParentHome(),
        '/parent-second': (context) => ParentSecondRoute(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class ParentHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentHomeState createState() => _ParentHomeState();
}

class _ParentHomeState extends State<ParentHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Go to second route'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(
              context,
              '/parent-second',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ParentSecondRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentSecondRouteState createState() => _ParentSecondRouteState();
}

class _ParentSecondRouteState extends State<ParentSecondRoute> {
  bool isChildRendered;

  @override
  void initState() {
    isChildRendered = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: isChildRendered
                ? ChildApp()
                : Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Center(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('Go to home'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: Center(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Checkbox(
                    value: isChildRendered,
                    onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                      isChildRendered = value;
                    }),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 5),
                  Text('Is child rendered?'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChildApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChildAppState createState() => _ChildAppState();
}

class _ChildAppState extends State<ChildApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Child',
      initialRoute: '/child-route-i-don\'t-want-to-see',
      routes: {
        '/child-route-i-don\'t-want-to-see': (context) => Container(
              color: Colors.brown,
            ),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not leave the `initialRoute` and `routes` to null in ChildApp and use `home` instead

Comment: I can't do that because I need the ChildApp to be an idependent app for other scenarious

Comment: @IosifPop Have you tried using the new Navigator designed for web? I'm not sure though if it can fix your problem... [Navigator 2.0](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation), [sample](https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade)

Comment: @rickimaru I did not try the new navigator since I think the issue is regarding the named routes and not regarding the navigator itself. I hope to find a configuration solution, if I don't find one I'm considering refactoring all navigatio, removing all named routes.

Comment: Hi @IosifPop, check my answer and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution with ModalRoute Class

You can solve it this way, by using the [ModalRoute Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute-class.html) and passing the current [route name defined in its settings](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteSettings-class.html) as parameter to the Child:

```dart
ChildApp(ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name)

class ChildApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final String route;

  const ChildApp(this.route);
  @override
  _ChildAppState createState() => _ChildAppState();
}

class _ChildAppState extends State<ChildApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Child',
      initialRoute: widget.route,
      routes: {
        widget.route: (context) => Container(
          color: Colors.brown,
        ),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

> name → String?
> The name of the route (e.g., "/settings"). [...]

---

#### Full example below:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ParentApp());
}

class ParentApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentAppState createState() => _ParentAppState();
}

class _ParentAppState extends State<ParentApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Parent',
      initialRoute: '/parent-home',
      routes: {
        '/parent-home': (context) => ParentHome(),
        '/parent-second': (context) => ParentSecondRoute(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class ParentHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentHomeState createState() => _ParentHomeState();
}

class _ParentHomeState extends State<ParentHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Go to second route'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(
              context,
              '/parent-second',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ParentSecondRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentSecondRouteState createState() => _ParentSecondRouteState();
}

class _ParentSecondRouteState extends State<ParentSecondRoute> {
  bool isChildRendered;

  @override
  void initState() {
    isChildRendered = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: isChildRendered
                ? ChildApp(ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name) // this line
                : Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Go to home'),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: Center(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Checkbox(
                    value: isChildRendered,
                    onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                      isChildRendered = value;
                    }),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 5),
                  Text('Is child rendered?'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChildApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final String route;

  const ChildApp(this.route); // and this one
  @override
  _ChildAppState createState() => _ChildAppState();
}

class _ChildAppState extends State<ChildApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Child',
      initialRoute: widget.route,
      routes: {
        widget.route: (context) => Container(
          color: Colors.brown,
        ),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

#### *Home*

[image]

#### *Second Route*

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Your solution is workin only if there is a single child that has a single route. In my case I have multiple diferent 'Child' apps with diferent routes each so I can't and don't want to have informations regarding the child routes in my 'Parent' app because I built the code using a lot of abstractization and generics. I just figured out that my question was not specific enough and I'm sorry for that.